# How to check values in memo field of a table in visualfoxpro?

Tags: database, field, visual-foxpro, foxpro, memo

How we have to check values in memo field of a table, I have tried the code mentioned below kindly go through the code and suggest me the appropriate code to use, thanks in advance!

```
Local nCount
Create Cursor mycursor(RecordS c(50))
IFExists=.F.
For nCount = 0 To Thisform.list3.ListCount
    Append Blank
    Replace RecordS With Alltrim(Thisform.list3.List(nCount))
    IFExists=.T.
Endfor
Delete From mycursor Where RecordS==""


If Alltrim(RecordS) == Alltrim(inv.tags)
    Messagebox("Succeeded")
Else
    Messagebox("Failed")
Endif
```

Comment: You don't have a memo-type field involved there. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: inv.tags in the above code consists of memo field

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to see if any of the items in the listbox 'list3' exists in field 'tags' of table 'inv'.

So you are making it more complicated than it needs to be.

```
select inv
llFound = .f.
for lnItem = 1 to thisform.list3.ListCount
    locate for alltrim(tags) == alltrim(thisform.list3.List(lnItem))
    if found()
        llFound = .t.
        exit
    endif
endfor

wait window iif(llFound, "Found.", "Not found.")
```

If you want to check if the value is contained anywhere in 'tags' rather than an exact match, replace the 'locate' line as follows:

```
locate for thisform.list3.List(lnItem) $ tags
```

Note that:

1. None of the above takes case into account, so you may need to wrap the strings in Lower() or Upper()
2. You are searching a memo field, so none of this will be optimised using indexes and could be very slow depending on the size of the 'invs' table.

Comment: Alan, thank you for putting such care into your code examples. This is a good thing because we write our answers not just for the original asker, but also for other people who take a look to see how things are done in Fox, and for each other. I've been using Fox each day for more than 20 years, and I'm still learning new stuff from other Fox professionals like you and sensei Rick Strahl.

Comment: Hi Alan, the above code returned the "Not Found" message even if it is there in the tags field, I have tried both the codes.

Comment: @ a.arun: `$` and `==` are case-sensitive, `=` is case-sensitive for the "MACHINE" collation and case-insensitive for "GENERAL". In Fox you cannot force collations for fields as you can in e.g. MS SQL Server, hence what matters is the collation set for your current session (which you can find out about via `? set('COLL')`). If the values in the list box have trailing blanks then you need to trim those via `RTRIM()` or `ALLTRIM()` as shown in Alan's first code fragment